# Swift 4.1 Foundation recompile

Tags: swift, compilation

I am trying to track down something that occurs inside the Swift Foundation framework, specifically related to the Codable protocol.
When I downloaded the source code (Version 4.1), and tried to compile it, I get very many errors, mostly caused by duplication of definitions already in the Stdlib.  Can anyone point me in the direction of documentation on how to import and compile with the Foundation source code?

Comment: just add `import Foundation` in the top of your code

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite of that.  If I import the foundation, everything then has double definitions.  I have the foundation in source code format from GitHub.  I have checked for any current references to "Import Foundation" in my base project, and there are none, but somehow Swift still knows about the definitions.  So I get many errors saying "Ambiguous type name 'Encoding' in 'String'", and other things.  Obviously there must be a better way of doing this that what I am trying.